# the WYSIWYG editor doesn't show up, drupal 7

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I installed the CKEditor in Drupal 7, following the steps in the documentation. I set up the right permissions and the text options and I cleared the caches, but when I want to add or edit some content, I have only the plain textarea.

However, when I navigate to *Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » CKEditor*. and edit the Filtered and Full HTML, the WYSIWYG editor shows up as it should when I expand the *Editor Appearence* tab, so I assume it's well installed.

What I find peculiar is that when I navigate to *Administration » Structure » Content types*, select a content type and click *manage fields* and *edit* for the `body` field
the area just below the text: "The default value for this field, used when creating new content." is still the old textarea. I don't find any option to change it, as if the WYSYWYG editor wouldn't exist.

Anyone has an idea, a solution? Is it something I miss here?
 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you lookup http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/install-ckeditor-in-drupal-7/ ?

Comment: I meant that the editor shows up only when I edit its configuration and display (on 'editor appearance'). But when I want to add or edit any content type, I have just the old plain box.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you've selected "Plain text" instead of "Filtered text" as your default text processing option.  To change this, navigate to *Administration » Structure » Content types*, select the content you experience problems with and click *manage fields* and *edit*  on the `body` field (and other text fields you want to use the wysywyg editor). Make sure that the preset text format for that text field is set to to one of the formats configured for wysywyg (e.g. *Filtered HTML*).

To make sure that *Filtered HTML* is selectable, you need to make sure that the setting for "Text processing" is set to *Filtered text* (not *Plain text*):

[image: screen dump]

Press *Save settings* after changing this.

Make sure that when you create content, a text format that is set up to use use WYSYWYG (e.g. *Filtered HTML*) is selected.  The screen dump below shows how the pull-down menu immediately below the text field for content should look like:

[image: screen dump]

**Other thinks to try when debugging a CKEditor setup:**

Here are some more tips on debugging a CKEditor setup.  They probably don't apply to you, but may help others that arrive at this question while searching for a cure for CKEditor blues:

1. Clear the cache:

   Remember to clear the cache after you've changed *any* setting that has something to do with wysiwyg.  Not clearing the cache is probably the most common source for CKEditor not showing up as you would expect.
2. Check out that roles are configured correctly:

   Navigate to your text formats: *Administration » Configuration » Content authoring  » Text formats* and ensure the roles are configured correctly.

   - Add the roles you want to use wysiwyg to *Filtered HTML* and *Full HTML*.
3. Check out that profiles are set up right:

   Navigate to your ckeditor profiles: *Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » CKeditor*

   Go to the profiles, and verify that the text formats for the profile are set, and the editor appearance is set properly.

   - Under *Basic Setup*, check the text formats that apply
   - Under *Editor Appearance*, set default state to enabled, and show the toggle.

PS: For a  secure use of WYSYWYG, I recommend using a custom text format filtered with the [WYSIWYG Filter](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter).  How you do this is described in this [tutorial](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/gisle/staging2/drupalprimer/drupal/mod_ckeditor.html). However, *first* get it working, *then* start tweaking to make it secure.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked all these settings and they are right, I have 'filtered html' selected and the permissions are in order. What I don't understand is why the default presentation for the body of each content type ("The default value for this field, used when creating new content." ) is still the old textarea. I don't find any option to change it, as if the WYSYWYG editor wouldn't exist. Thought I checked it in the Editor Appearance, and it's properly installed. I don't know what else I could do here...

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I debugged it, finally..:) I got an error message and I realized that it was looking for a path which actually didn't exist in my Drupal files...I had to change the path settings in Ckeditor- edit Global Profile, and now it's working!!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when I create a WYSIWYG field, and doesn't load the editor I do the following:

1. Check the *Enable by default* for the *Filtered HTML* profile:

*Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Wysiwyg profiles »
CKEditor profile for Filtered HTML*
[image]

2. Set the Text processing in the Content Type settings:

*Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » Article » Manage fields
Content*
[image]