# All WYSIWYG Editors do not show up on site

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have installed the CKEditor module, but my editing block doesn't show up properly:

[image]

I've followed all suggestions listed here:
[the WYSIWYG editor doesn't show up, drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109256/the-wysiwyg-editor-doesnt-show-up-drupal-7)

In previous websites I've done, once installed, I never had problems like this.  The "Full HTML" or "Filtered HTML" dropdown is gone, and the editor, though looks to be a WYSIWYG editor, isn't CKEditor, and as such, doesn't show the options that I've chosen in CKEditor Configuration pages.

Here's an example of another site I've used it on, where it works properly:
[image: Correct CKEditor]

**EDIT**
I have now tried the CKEditor module alone, and have tried each WYSIWYG editors (uninstalling other modules each time so they're independent).  Even after selecting which module to use for text (via the instructions on the link above), the WYSIWYG editor will not change from what you see above.  This includes 1) only showing limited options that I can't change, 2) not allowing my to change between Full & Filtered HTML & other options.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: *and the editor, though nice, isn't the CKEditor options that I've chosen.* what does 'nice' means here?

Comment: As in, it is more than just a plain text editor.  There is obviously some WYSIWYG functionality, but it is not CKEditor.

Comment: double check that multiple text formats exist in `/admin/config/content/formats` If only 1 exits, then there is no point for CKEditor to show a select box.

Comment: Your other site do not have any editor except CKeditor, then why are you not just checking removing nice from your questioned site. So you will be sure that nothing coming from there. Then in will be pure comparison, I think. Do not disable, completely remove to check.

Comment: Are you using Ckeditor module from drupal.org OR are you combining WYSIWIG +CKeditor?

Comment: I've now tried CKEditor module, AND WYSIWYG module (with CKEditor, YUI, and TinyMCE).  I tried each independently, uninstalling everything else.  STILL, no WYSIWYG editors are showing.  I'm going to update my question when I get to computer.

Comment: Sounds like you have a JavaScript error on the page or perhaps didn't install it right.